# How to bypass CRLF tags in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, escaping

I have a curl request in which there is crlf tags as it's multipart form

I have to pass variable to it. Scenario is like

```
name=xyz
a=$'\"$name\"\x0d\x0a'
gives output
"$name"
```

Expected output

`xyz`

Any way to do this.? Thanks

Comment: I'm not clear about how curl tag multipart form enters into this. Does `name=xyz;a=$''"$name"'\x0d\x0a' ; echo "$a"` help? Otherwise I don't have anything to offer on this. Good luck!

Comment: Anything wrong with `a="$name"$'\x0d\x0a'`?

Answer (score 1):

```
name=xyz
printf -v a "%s\x0d\0a" "$name"
echo "$a" | od -cx
0000000   x   y   z  \r  \n
           7978    0d7a    000a
0000005
```